# Lennard-Jones potential can be valid at 0.2 Angstrom Distance between two particles?

Tags: solid-state-physics, potential, potential-energy, phonons, graphene

I have modeled a graphene-vacuum-graphene system. Here two graphene sheets connected by L-J potential through vacuum gap (Phonon transfer through vacuum). I have simulated it considering 0.2 to 10 Angstrom (Phonon conductance plot). Though I know at 0.2 A, repulsive force will be too high, but Is it invalid or impossible situation?
N.B: Using Molecular dynamics simulation,  i got thermal root mean square distance 0.17 Angstrom.
LJ parameters:
Epsilon=2.39e-3 (ev)
Sigma=3.4148)(Angstrom)

Comment: Lennard-Jones potential is a model interaction characterized by the two parameters $\varepsilon$ and $\sigma$. Without information about the chosen values for such parameters, it would be impossible to say something.

Comment: The Bohr radius is around 0 5 Angstrom, so when your separation is of that order (a bit larger for bigger atoms) the atoms are essentially on top of each other and I would expect to have to do detailed modelling of the electronic structure, and would not expect accurate results from a long range effective potential like Lennard-Jones

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 the LJ paramters are epsilon= 2.39e-3 (ev) and sigma=3.4148 Angstrom

Comment: Could you say more about the physical system or setup you like to model ? What do you mean with graphene vacuum graphene ?

Comment: In the graphitic state the distance between the sheets is 0.35 nm. So I guess by choosing a distance below that you imply a stronger bonding, rather than two loosely bonded grahene sheets.